# Arduino: Only 3 things at same time in loop

Tags: arduino

I  got a code to run 14 StepperMotors via AccelStepper libary.
But I want just to run 3 StepperMotors at the same time.
If 4 (ore more) StepperMotor should be used, then the 4th  should wait until one of the other 3 has finished.
Means: Start a StepperMotor when a "free slot" is available.
How can i do this?

Here is my Code:

```
  #include <Max3421e.h>
  #include <Usb.h>
  #include <AndroidAccessory.h>
  #include <AccelStepper.h>

  #define VALUE_OFF 0x0
  #define VALUE_ON 0x1
  #define COMMAND_DRINK 0x2
  #define COMMAND_LED 0x3

  AndroidAccessory acc("Manufacturer",
                 "Model",
                 "Description",
                 "1.0",
                 "http://nichtsda.com",
                 "0000000012345678");


  //pin definitions.  must be PWM-capable pins!
  const int redPin = 2;
  const int greenPin = 3;
  const int bluePin = 4;


  AccelStepper stepper1   (AccelStepper::DRIVER, 23, 12);
  AccelStepper stepper2   (AccelStepper::DRIVER, 27, 11);
  AccelStepper stepper3   (AccelStepper::DRIVER, 31, 11);
  AccelStepper stepper4   (AccelStepper::DRIVER, 35, 11);
  AccelStepper stepper5   (AccelStepper::DRIVER, 39, 11);
  AccelStepper stepper6   (AccelStepper::DRIVER, 43, 11);
  AccelStepper stepper7   (AccelStepper::DRIVER, 47, 11);
  AccelStepper stepper8   (AccelStepper::DRIVER, 51, 11);
  AccelStepper stepper9   (AccelStepper::DRIVER, 24, 11);
  AccelStepper stepper10  (AccelStepper::DRIVER, 28, 11);
  AccelStepper stepper11  (AccelStepper::DRIVER, 32, 11);
  AccelStepper stepper12  (AccelStepper::DRIVER, 36, 11);
  AccelStepper stepper13  (AccelStepper::DRIVER, 40, 11);
  AccelStepper stepper14  (AccelStepper::DRIVER, 44, 11);



  //int stepPin[16]={23,27,31,35,39,43,47,51,24,28,32,36,40,44,48,52};
  int multiplikator = 60000;
  int MengeZutat[16];


  const int max_red = 255;
  const int max_green = 255;
  const int max_blue = 200;

  byte colors[3] = {0, 0, 0}; //array to store led brightness values
  byte rcvmsg[16];



void setup()
{

//set all three of our led pins to output
pinMode(redPin, OUTPUT);
pinMode(greenPin, OUTPUT);
pinMode(bluePin, OUTPUT);
Serial.begin(115200);
acc.powerOn();


stepper1.setMaxSpeed(1800.0);
stepper1.setAcceleration(1000.0);

stepper2.setMaxSpeed(1100.0);
stepper2.setAcceleration(1000.0);

stepper3.setMaxSpeed(1800.0);
stepper3.setAcceleration(1000.0);


stepper4.setMaxSpeed(1800.0);
stepper4.setAcceleration(1000.0);

stepper5.setMaxSpeed(1800.0);
stepper5.setAcceleration(1000.0);

stepper6.setMaxSpeed(1800.0);
stepper6.setAcceleration(1000.0);

stepper7.setMaxSpeed(1800.0);
stepper7.setAcceleration(1000.0);

stepper8.setMaxSpeed(1800.0);
stepper8.setAcceleration(1000.0);

stepper9.setMaxSpeed(1800.0);
stepper9.setAcceleration(1000.0);

stepper10.setMaxSpeed(1800.0);
stepper10.setAcceleration(1000.0);

stepper11.setMaxSpeed(1800.0);
stepper11.setAcceleration(1000.0);

stepper12.setMaxSpeed(1800.0);
stepper12.setAcceleration(1000.0);

stepper13.setMaxSpeed(1800.0);
stepper13.setAcceleration(1000.0);

stepper14.setMaxSpeed(1800.0);
stepper14.setAcceleration(1000.0);

}



void loop()
{

if (acc.isConnected()) {
acc.read(rcvmsg, sizeof(rcvmsg), 1);






 if (rcvmsg[14] == COMMAND_LED ) {
  byte value = rcvmsg[15];
  if (value == VALUE_ON) {
    colors[0] = rcvmsg[0] + 128;
    colors[1] = rcvmsg[1] + 128;
    colors[2] = rcvmsg[2] + 128;
    analogWrite(redPin, map(colors[0], 0, 255, 0, max_red));
    analogWrite(greenPin, map(colors[1], 0, 255, 0, max_green));
    analogWrite(bluePin, map(colors[2], 0, 255, 0, max_blue));
  }
  else if (value = VALUE_OFF) {
    colors[0] = 0;
    colors[1] = 0;
    colors[2] = 0;
    analogWrite(redPin, map(colors[0], 0, 255, 0, max_red));
    analogWrite(greenPin, map(colors[1], 0, 255, 0, max_green));
    analogWrite(bluePin, map(colors[2], 0, 255, 0, max_blue));
  }
 }



 if (rcvmsg[14] == COMMAND_DRINK ) {
  byte value = rcvmsg[15];
  if (value == VALUE_ON) {

    //int sleepPin[16]={25,29,33,37,41,45,49,53,22,26,30,34,38,42,46,50};


    stepper1.move(rcvmsg[0]*multiplikator);
    stepper1.setEnablePin(25);

    stepper2.move(rcvmsg[1]*multiplikator);
    stepper2.setEnablePin(29);

    stepper3.move(rcvmsg[2]*multiplikator);
    stepper3.setEnablePin(33);

    stepper4.move(rcvmsg[3]*multiplikator);
    stepper4.setEnablePin(25);

    stepper5.move(rcvmsg[4]*multiplikator);
    stepper5.setEnablePin(37);

    stepper6.move(rcvmsg[5]*multiplikator);
    stepper6.setEnablePin(41);

    stepper7.move(rcvmsg[6]*multiplikator);
    stepper7.setEnablePin(45);

    stepper8.move(rcvmsg[7]*multiplikator);
    stepper8.setEnablePin(49);

    stepper9.move(rcvmsg[8]*multiplikator);
    stepper9.setEnablePin(53);

    stepper10.move(rcvmsg[9]*multiplikator);
    stepper10.setEnablePin(22);

    stepper11.move(rcvmsg[10]*multiplikator);
    stepper11.setEnablePin(26);

    stepper12.move(rcvmsg[11]*multiplikator);
    stepper12.setEnablePin(30);

    stepper13.move(rcvmsg[12]*multiplikator);
    stepper13.setEnablePin(34);

    stepper14.move(rcvmsg[13]*multiplikator);
    stepper14.setEnablePin(38);

  }
  else if (value == VALUE_OFF ) {



    stepper1.run();
    if (stepper1.isRunning() == false) {
      stepper1.disableOutputs();
    }

    stepper2.run();
    if (stepper2.isRunning() == false) {
      stepper2.disableOutputs();
    }


    stepper3.run();
    if (stepper3.isRunning() == false) {
      stepper3.disableOutputs();
    }

    stepper4.run();
    if (stepper4.isRunning() == false) {
      stepper4.disableOutputs();
    }

    stepper5.run();
    if (stepper5.isRunning() == false) {
      stepper5.disableOutputs();
    }

    stepper6.run();
    if (stepper6.isRunning() == false) {
      stepper6.disableOutputs();
    }

    stepper7.run();
    if (stepper7.isRunning() == false) {
      stepper7.disableOutputs();
    }

    stepper8.run();
    if (stepper8.isRunning() == false) {
      stepper8.disableOutputs();
    }


    stepper9.run();
    if (stepper9.isRunning() == false) {
      stepper9.disableOutputs();
    }

    stepper10.run();
    if (stepper10.isRunning() == false) {
      stepper10.disableOutputs();
    }

    stepper11.run();
    if (stepper11.isRunning() == false) {
      stepper11.disableOutputs();
    }

    stepper12.run();
    if (stepper12.isRunning() == false) {
      stepper12.disableOutputs();
    }


    stepper13.run();
    if (stepper13.isRunning() == false) {
      stepper13.disableOutputs();
    }

    stepper14.run();
    if (stepper14.isRunning() == false) {
      stepper14.disableOutputs();
    }




  }
}



}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your library.

There are two main ways: using arrays or using pointers.

With arrays you make a queue of actions and execute only the first three, shifting the queue down whenever an action is completed.
But how do you know it's complete, that's another story altogether.

Using pointers, you create three slots for execution:

```
AccelStepper *slot1;
AccelStepper *slot2;
Accelstepper *slot3;
```

and then load them with the pointer to the proper motor.

```
slot1 = &stepper1;
```

Now slot1 is stepper1 until you change that.
Still you must know when a motor has finished and update all that, so you'll probably end up with a queue array.

My suggestion would be to take a completely different approach:
use one of the analog inputs to measure average current supply to the servo board and delay execution if it is above a certain value.
So your program runs and you have overload protection.

Actually after writing all this I realized you could just have a counter which increments when a motor is started and decrements when it ends and avoid starting above a certain number.
But this simple method requires again that you know when the motor has finished and could lead to a program hangup, which should then be solved by a timeout.

Hope this all is useful.